# Contour Widget customize

Tags: foundry-contour

Is there any way to customize Contour boards (table, calculate board, etc) to display them in dashboard or at least in notebook version?  I'm looking for a classic setting, such as changing the size, the color of the font, changing the color of the borders, etc.

I have searched in the official documentation, but I don't find anything about it.